# Itemモデルにliking_userを含めた状態で取得する方法

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, api

railsでapiを作っているのですが自分がやりたいような設計にできないので質問させていただきます。Itemモデルのliking_users（Itemをお気に入りしているユーザー）を含めた状態でTagモデルの中のItemモデルを複数取得したいです。最終的には下記のように取得したいです。

```
{ tags: [
    {  "id": 1,
       "name": Mens,
       "items": [
          {
             "id": 1,
             "name": shirts,
             "liking_users": [
                    {
                       "id": 1,
                       "name": Tom
                     },
                     { 
                       "id": 2,
                       "name": Steve
                     }
              ]
           }
        ]
     }
   ]
}
```

現状のコードは、

models/tag.rb

```
class Tag < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :items  
end
```

models/item.rb

```
class Item < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :likes, dependent: :destroy
   has_many :liking_users, through: :likes, source: :user
end
```

models/user.rb

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :likes, dependent: :destroy
   has_many :like_items, through: :likes, source: :item
end
```

models/like.rb

```
class Like < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :item
   belongs_to :user
end
```

app/apis/api/v1/tags.rb

```
module API
  module V1
    class Tags < Grape::API
      resource :tags do

  　　   desc 'GET /api/v1/tags/:id'
  　　　  params do
     　　　 requires :id, type: Integer, desc: "Tag id."
    　　　end
   　　　 get '/:id' do
    　  　　tag = Tag.find(params[:id])
     　　　 @tag = tag.items.  #この行をどう書けばいいかわからないです、、
    　　　end
      end
    end
  end
end
```

もしよければ、どなたか回答して頂けないでしょうか。宜しくお願いします。

Comment: Tag モデルはありますか？または、Tag モデルをどう書けば良いかわからない、という質問でしょうか？

Comment: すみませんTagモデルを記述するのを忘れていたので編集しました。GET /api/v1/tags/:idで @tag = tag.itemsとするとliking_usersを含まないまま表示されてしまうので、どのように書けばliking_usersをitemの中に含めたまま表示できるかを教えて頂きたいです。

Answer (score 0):

スミマセン。Grape を使っていることに後から気付きました。
Grape のやり方はわからないので、別の方の回答を期待してくださいませ。

Rails なら分かるので、ヒントだけでもと思い、投稿します。
ご参考になれば幸いです。

```
[3] pry(main)> tag.as_json(root: true, include: { items: { include: :liking_users }})
{
    "tag" => {
           "id" => 1,
         "name" => "Men",
        "items" => [
            [0] {
                          "id" => 1,
                      "tag_id" => 1,
                        "name" => "shirts",
                "liking_users" => [
                    [0] {
                          "id" => 1,
                        "name" => "Tom"
                    },
                    [1] {
                          "id" => 2,
                        "name" => "Steve"
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
}
```